# How to validate a JSON string with escaped quotes using Python

Tags: python, json, validation, parsing

I am using json.loads to parse a JSON string. However, it identifies the string as invalid JSON when it contains escaped double quotes. Since the string itself is valid, how could I parse it correctly without modifying the input string (i.e. using \\" instead of \"). Here is my code:

```
import json 

a = '{"name":"Nickname \"John\" Doe", "age":31, "Salary":25000}'

print ("initial strings given - \n", a) 

try: 
    json_object1 = json.loads(a) 

    print ("Is valid json? true") 

except ValueError as e: 
    print ("Is valid json? false")
```

Thanks!

Comment: But aren't _all_ of the quote marks in that string effectively escaped, regardless of whether a "\" precedes them? `'"\"'` evaluates to the same string as `'""'`.

Comment: Letting `json` generate the JSON from a dict would be simpler: `a = json.dumps(dict(name='Nickname "John" Doe', age=31, Salary=25000))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the backslash itself is an escape character, you need to either escape it, or use a raw string (simply with the `r` prefix):

```
a = '{"name":"Nickname \\"John\\" Doe", "age":31, "Salary":25000}'
```

or

```
a = r'{"name":"Nickname \"John\" Doe", "age":31, "Salary":25000}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Its the `\` that need escaping to make valid `json`:

```
#soJsonEscapeQuotes

import json 

a = '{"name":"Nickname \\"John\\" Doe", "age":31, "Salary":25000}'

print ("initial strings given - \n", a) 

try: 
    json_object1 = json.loads(a) 

    print ("Is valid json? true") 

except ValueError as e: 
    print ("Is valid json? false")
```

Output:

```
initial strings given - 
 {"name":"Nickname \"John\" Doe", "age":31, "Salary":25000}
Is valid json? true
```